# Rendering HTML values within a Pandas Dataframe using Dash

Tags: python, html, pandas, plotly-dash

I am currently using Plotly Dash to render a pandas dataframe as a table. A few of the columns within the dataframe actually contain HTML tags and I would like to render those elements fully using the dash_table module.

As an example I would like to render the table with the HTML values below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'Name': ['John', 'Jane', 'Mary'],
'Description': ['<strong>Tall</strong> and <em>smart</em>',
                '<strong>Short</strong> and <em>funny</em>', 
                '<strong>Tall</strong> and <em>athletic</em>']})
```

Currently Dash displays the table as so, where the HTML data is just printed as a string:

[image]

I would like to display the table reflecting the actual HTML tags like so:

[image]

Any help is appreciated, thank you!